# Better time to compile/install/test cycle

Tags: android, time, installation, apk, dalvik

my project is growing large, and I am facing the following problem: the compile/transform-to-dalvik/install cycle takes too long.

It takes around 2 minutes since I press F11 (or ^F11) until the dialog to choose the device is shown, and around another minute from there until the application is shown on the phone.

3 minutes may not seem like a waste of time, but it breaks the concentration (actually, I am writing this post during those 3 minutes).

Do you have any trick to avoid this? Any way to avoid the full dalvik conversion when only a couple of classes have been modified? Any way to live-copy the classes to the phone without the need of the .class-dalvik-.apk-copy-install cycle?

Any other hint?

Comment: How big is your project? Maybe it could be splitted into a few separate projects?

Comment: We're facing the same issue on our windows machines.  On our Macs, the same project compiles very quickly still.  Hopefully this is addressed in future ADT versions.

Comment: It currently has more than 3000 files (including java, drawables, layouts and some assets). If you do not propose another option, I'll have to divide it... but it will be hard.